# Facebook without JS?

Tags: javascript, facebook

The mobile version of Facebook allows the site to function without JavaScript.

I have JS disabled on my Chrome Android browser.

When I try to make a comment on a post, the POST button is initially grey AND disabled; however, when I type in anything it goes blue and becomes enabled.

How is this possible without JS?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Visiting mobile facebook in Firefox with JS blocked results in a comment submit button that is always blue and enabled and will submit the form.

Comment: @KФ — Nonsense. It worked just fine when I tested it just now.

Comment: @Quenin youre right. my bad. Chrome somehow managed to cache the page or something

Comment: 4 years later, i want to say .. thank you :) after i disabled JS i've switched to a very light version of facebook with saved me 90% of my internet bandwidth cause internet is very expensive in egypt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML5 validation and CSS

```css
input:invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

form:invalid [type="submit"] {
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Enter a Name</label>
  <input type="text" required/>
  <br />
  <br />
  <label>Enter an email address:</label>
  <input type="email" required/>
  
  <input type="submit" />
</form>


----------
```

If you want it disabled, you can have two buttons and toggle their display

```css
input:invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

form [type="submit"][disabled] {
    display: none;
}

form:invalid [type="submit"][disabled] {
    display: inline;
}


form:invalid [type="submit"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Enter a Name</label>
  <input type="text" required/>
  <br />
  <br />
  <label>Enter an email address:</label>
  <input type="email" required/>
  
  <input type="submit" />
  <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Comment: however. it is disabled and it does not post when greyed.

Comment: You can easily swap out the button with a disabled one.

Comment: Added example with the disabled button.